# Angular - Remove FormGroup from FormArray in forEach loop based on matching criteria

Tags: angular

I have below code

```
    (this.formGroups.get('items') as FormArray).controls.forEach((item, index, object) => {
        console.log(item.value.attributeDisplayName);
        if (item.value.attributeDisplayName === '') {
            object.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
```

I am not sure whether the code is correct or not, however it is not getting executed. Basically I need to remove all the object(s)/formGroup(s) from my `formGroups` array where `attributeDisplayName` is empty.

`item.value` gives me the current object with properties where `attributeDisplayName` resides. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'removeAt' is the proper way of removing single object/control from a FormArray, but if you use it with multiple controls in loop it results in removing some but not others.

This might be happening due to removing from the same index you are looping over, to overcome this you can first identify the unwanted controls and then remove them in reverse.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-g7xhuq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
deleteEmpty() {
let indexToRemove: number[] = [];

let fromArray = this.form.get('items') as FormArray;
fromArray.controls.forEach((control, index) => {
  if (!control.value.attributeDisplayName) {
    indexToRemove.push(index);
  }
});
indexToRemove.reverse().forEach((index) => {
  fromArray.removeAt(index);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is going to clear your whole formarray.

```
this.form.get('images')['controls'].splice(0,this.form.get('images')['controls'].length);
```